# ¿Cómo agregar uso de sesiones en mi código PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo este código y no sé poner un `session_start()`. ¿podrían auxiliar?.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "usuario";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$se = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE usuario = '$_POST[usuario]'";
$result = $conn->query($se);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<script>
        alert("Usuario ya fué registrado");
        window.history.go(-1);

       </script>
       ';
    }
} else {

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (usuario, clave)
VALUES ('$_POST[usuario]', '$_POST[clave]')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo '<script>
alert("Exito fué registrado");
window.history.go(-1);

</script>
';
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Ten mucho cuidado con ese código, sufre numerosos problemas. El más grave es el de inyección SQL. Tienes un ejemplo de cómo usar `session_start()` y, a su vez, solucionar los problemas de seguridad en tu código en este gist: [https://gist.github.com/ojgarciab/4f706704640d3f4bb6b4acfcaba59eeb#file-login-mysqli-php-L3](https://gist.github.com/ojgarciab/4f706704640d3f4bb6b4acfcaba59eeb#file-login-mysqli-php-L3)

Answer (score 1):

Solo hazlo así:

```
<?php
session_start();
// resto del código
```

Comment: Gracias lo intentare.

Comment: no olvides los $_SESSION["username"] para imprimir los datos de usuario, dependiendo de que campos desees imprimir